# How to Make a Query to Return Non-Dup values From Two Tables

Tags: sql

Suppose the following:

```
Table Parts
--------------------------------
ID  Category  Name        Price
--------------------------------
1    A        Processor    100
2    A        MotherBoard   80
3    B        Memory Card   40
4    B        HD            70
5    C        Cooler        10

Table Product_Views
    -----------------------------------
    Customer   Date            Part_ID
    -----------------------------------
    Bill      mar-24-15 17:45   1
    Wallace   mar-25-15 08:17   4
    Heather   mar-25-15 08:43   1
    Chuck     mar-25-15 09:01   5
    Cindy     mar-25-15 11:23   1
```

How can I build a SQL query in order to retrieve most viewed parts showing: Category, price and number of views, grouped by Category, WITHOUT a sum on Price column? Must I do a subquery or there's a trick to do that in a simple [INNER/LEFT/RIGHT] JOIN?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Does it matter? I'd like to know just about SQL but, nevertheless, I'm using SAS. Otherwise this is a recurrent issue and I'd like to have a generic solution, wich I would use in a plenty of situations, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.ID, p.Name, p.price, Count(v.*) "Number of Views"
from parts p 
join product_views v 
on p.id = v.part_id
group by p.ID, p.Name, p.price
order by Count(v.*) desc
```

Something along those lines should work.

EDIT for category:

Sorry I've been out for a while.  What do you want to do with the category?  If you just need it included for analysis you can just add it to the select and group by statements, like the following:

```
select p.ID, p.Category, p.Name, p.price, Count(v.*) "Number of Views"
from parts p 
join product_views v 
on p.id = v.part_id
group by p.ID, p.Category, p.Name, p.price
order by Count(v.*) desc
```

If however you want to see how many views there are per category, you will either need to average your price or leave the price off.  If you think about it, in a category you have multiple items with different prices each.  So you need some way to unify those prices in order to have a single price point per category.  Generally (not always), the average price is the most indicative price of how a category is doing.  A query to look at the information at the category level would look something like the following:

```
select p.Category, AVG(p.price) "Average Price", Count(v.*) "Number of Views"
from parts p 
join product_views v 
on p.id = v.part_id
group by p.Category
order by Count(v.*) desc
```

In order to leave off the price, just remove the AVG(p.price) "Average Price" from the query.

You can compare this last query to the previous one and see that the differences are all in the select and group by statements.  The select is going to have all of the different things that you want to see and the group by statement is going to choose at what level you want to see those things.  So if you want to see how your categories are doing on a whole, then the most detail that you want to group by will be just the category column.  If you want to see how well each item is doing, then you will want to group by the ID or name of each item.

Comment: thanks for responding. Unfortunately I forgot a very important feature of my model wich was not represented in the former DB model. I've made an edit in my question. If you have an answer for this new chalenge, I would be pleased to know. Thanks again.